# Learning python the hard way, exercise 1 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

Extremely new to this so this is likely caused by my own inexperience, so apologizing in advance here.
I know this is said a lot on these questions but I'm trying to learn python using 'Learn python the hard way.'. 
I've become stuck on exercise 1: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex1.html

On windows we have to create a text file in notepad ++ called 'ex1.py' and run it in PowerShell using the command 'python ex1.py'.

Problem is every time I try, I get this error:

```
File "ex1.py", line 1

   Print "Hello World!"
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

These types of errors are mentioned on the tutorial page but it only explains they point out errors and to use what it says in the 'SyntaxError:' to search for the answer if what it says is too cryptic to understand. Why is the caret pointing towards the "? What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated by this newbie.

Comment: `print("Hello World!")` python3 vs python2 print statements

Comment: You are using `Print`, not `print`. Case matters! Python cannot detect that you made the error until the next token is complete (at the end of the string), as the name `Print` could be combined with some other operator (`Print + "Hello World!"` would be legal Python syntax).

Comment: Remember to read the every little detail, and pay attention to the WYSS section.

Comment: Jesus, you guys are quick! Thanks a lot everyone, didn't even noticed I used upper cases, gotta get better at spotting the difference. Thanks again and not for getting mad at my stupid mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is a case-sensitive language.  [`print`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-print_stmt) needs to be lowercase:

```
print "Hello World!"
```

If you are using Python 3.x, you also need parenthesis because [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is a function:

```
print("Hello World!")
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me with my silly mistake! New to this site, should I leave this up for other people or delete the post?

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error because `Print` should be `print`.